# forming a new data frame using zip, but getting an error

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a numpy_array called `playoff_teams`:

```
playoff_teams = np.sort(playoff_seeds['team'])
playoff_teams[:7]

array([1115, 1124, 1139, 1140, 1143, 1155, 1165], dtype=int64)
```

I have a data_frame called `reg`:

```
       season daynum    wteam   wscore  lteam   lscore  wloc    numot
108122  2010    7       1143     75      1293    70       H     0
108123  2010    7       1314     88      1198    72       H     0
108124  2010    7       1326     100     1108    60       H     0
108125  2010    7       1393     75      1107    43       H     0
108126  2010    9       1143     95      1178    61       H     0
```

I then loop over the teams and perform the following action:

```
for teams in  playoff_teams:
    games = reg[(reg['wteam'] == teams) | (reg['lteam']== teams)]
    last_six = sum(games.tail(6)['wteam'] == teams)
    zipped = zip(team, last_six)
```

I get an error

```
TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration
```

I need to form a new data frame in following format:

```
col_1   col_2
team_1   last_six
team_2   last_six
team_3   last_six
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#sum) returns a number, not something that you can iterate over while [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip) needs iterables so I think your problem is there.

```
last_six = sum(games.tail(6)['wteam'] == teams)  # Number
zipped = zip(team, last_six)  # Error because last_six is not iterable
```

You could store the results in a list (that might be a dict too) for instance :

```
new_data = []
for teams in  playoff_teams:
    games = reg[(reg['wteam'] == teams) | (reg['lteam']== teams)]
    last_six = sum(games.tail(6)['wteam'] == teams)
    new_data.append((teams, last_six))
```

Then build your data frame using `DataFrame.from_items` or `DataFrame.from_dict` (if you chose a dict and not a list).

Comment: yes I used itertools.repeat on both the arguments of zip, but my ipython notebook gets struck. I think the operation is bit expensive

Comment: Why not return a plain `tuple` such as `(team, last_six)` ?

Comment: using tuple I will get an o/p like this : `(1115, 5)
(1124, 5)` but how do I form a data frame out of it?

Comment: I edited my answer. You could use the `DataFrame.from_items` function

Comment: Great. I got it. I dont why the other solution was deleted?

Comment: Don't know I didn't see it!